# Windows Service Programming

Tags: winapi, service

I'm writing a windows service and I need to pass some parameters into the service, does anyone know how I would go about this?

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY svcTable[2] = {0};
    svcTable[0].lpServiceName = (LPWSTR)svcName.c_str();
    svcTable[0].lpServiceProc = (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)TRPC::ServiceMain;

    std::wstring* str = new std::wstring(TEXT("Hello World"));

//  I want to pass say, str in argv[0];

    StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(svcTable);
}

void TRPC::ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPWSTR* argv)
{
    Access argv here...
}
```

ServiceMain is a static definition within the class so as to conform with __stdcall, but what I want to do is populate **agrv** with my OWN set of allocated strings before StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() is called, so that I can use the parameters from within the method.  Any ideas?

Comment: The arguments for the service are supplied from outside the service. It seems to me that you are confused on the matter. You seem to think that the arguments are originating in your code

Comment: May be use `ChangeServiceConfig` before `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` and change a binary path there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Service Control Manager calls `ServiceMain()` from within `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` when starting the service. The only way to pass parameters to `ServiceMain()` itself are to:

1. Put the parameters in the SCM UI (the "Services" applet in the Control Panel) when starting the service by clicking on the "Start" button in the service's properties dialog.  These parameters are not persistent, though.  One you close the UI, they are discarded.
2. In a call to the `StartService()` function in your own app code.

The alternatives are to either:

1. Put command-line parameters in the service registration, then the service can use `GetCommandLine()` when needed.
2. Put the values somewhere - Registry, Database, INI/XML file, etc - that the service can access when needed.